# MYSQL GROUP BY multiple derived tables?

Tags: mysql

I have this query which does some calculations based on some derived tables that are linked with an `INNER JOIN`.

At the moment I have a `WHERE` clause which pulls out one id at a time.  But how can I make it list *all* the ids?

I have tried `GROUP BY` in various places but can't figure it out.

My query so far is as follows:

```
SELECT 
equipment_id, 
service_duration,
available_duration,
(available_duration / service_duration)*100 AS availability
FROM (
SELECT
SUM(service_end_time - service_start_time) AS service_duration
FROM(   
    SELECT equipment_id, 
    (CASE  
    END) AS service_start_time,
    (CASE  
    END) AS service_end_time
FROM t1 
WHERE equipment_id = 'EX123' 
  )AS A
) AS B
JOIN(
SELECT equipment_id, 
       SUM(available_end_time - available_start_time) AS available_duration
FROM (
    SELECT equipment_id,  
    (CASE 
    END) AS available_start_time,
    (CASE       
    END) AS available_end_time
FROM t2 
WHERE equipment_id = 'EX123'
  ) AS C
) AS D
ON equipment_id=D.equipment_id
```

What I want to do is replace the `WHERE` clause with a `GROUP BY` to list all the ids, or similar, but getting that to work is beyond my skill level...  Any help greatly appreciated  :)

Comment: It would be easier to provide the solution if you can provide DB schema, sample data and expected result, you can use SqlFiddle.com for just that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below:

```
    SELECT 
    equipment_id, service_duration, available_duration,
    (available_duration / service_duration)*100 AS availability
    FROM 
    (
            SELECT equipment_id,
            SUM(service_end_time - service_start_time) AS service_duration
            FROM
            (   
                    SELECT equipment_id, 
                        (CASE ... END) AS service_start_time,
                        (CASE  ...  END) AS service_end_time
                    FROM t1         
            ) AS A
            GROUP BY equipment_id
    ) AS B
    JOIN
    (
            SELECT equipment_id, 
            SUM(available_end_time - available_start_time) AS available_duration
            FROM 
            (
                SELECT equipment_id,  
                (CASE ... END) AS available_start_time,
                (CASE ... END) AS available_end_time
                FROM t2         
            ) AS C
            GROUP BY equipment_id
    ) AS D
    ON equipment_id=D.equipment_id
```

Comment: There is actually a problem with this now I have tested it properly, the query assigns both sub-query outputs to each id

Comment: See edit above - Thanks Minesh for getting me going in the right direction  :)

Comment: @xgstr Not sure about the edit, please clarify what change is done.

Comment: peer edit thing has stopped it going through..  Needed to be more specific with the joins.. i.e. needed to be D.equipment_id in the initial select and ON B.equipment_id=D.equipment_id at then end to avoid assigning all results to all ids

Answer (score 1):

Try this (replace my field names with your field names):

```
SELECT 
    a.emp_id, 
    service_duration,
    available_duration 

FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            emp_id,
            SUM(service_end_time - service_start_time) AS service_duration

        FROM 
            data 

        GROUP BY 
            emp_id 
    ) a

    JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            emp_id, 
            SUM(available_end_time - available_start_time) AS available_duration

        FROM 
            data 

        GROUP BY
            emp_id
    ) b 
    ON a.emp_id = b.emp_id 

GROUP BY
    a.emp_id
```